# How to fix the HTML Formatting in Outlook 2016

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I have a Problem with my HTML Code that is generated for a Web Form.
It works in all Programs except in Outlook.

Is there some way to fix this?
Because I realy dont want that a customer gets an E-Mail like this :/

**MY HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
<div class="inner">
<div class="header sitename"><img src="CENSORED" width="168" height="47" alt="CENSORED" /></div>
<p>Schönen guten Tag {name},<br /> Ihre Anfrage ist bei uns eingegangen. Wir bemühen uns um eine schnelle Antwort, um Ihnen weiterhelfen zu können. Sie hören bald wieder von uns!</p>
<div class="footer">CENSORED</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**MY CSS:**

```
/*
All classes will be replaced with style attribute.
This is done because some web mail (included google mail) strike out all style reference.

Due to this replacement the following statements will not work:
#id { color: red; }
table { border: 1px solid black; }

Related documentation: http://www.fox.ra.it/forum/enquiries-processors/11143-e-mail-notification-models.html
*/


body
{
       background-color: #fafafa;
}


.wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 24px 0 24px 0;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container
{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 680px;
    min-width: 280px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.9);
    margin: auto;
}

.inner
{
    color: #505050;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 24px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
}

.sitename
{
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 34px;
}

.header
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
        background-color: #ffffff
}

.fields-list
{
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.field-element
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.field-title
{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0;
}

.field-content
{
    margin: 4px 4px 16px 4px;
}

.field-table-href
{
}

.footer
{
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
    margin-top: 32px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #707070;
        background-color: #ffffff
}
```

It looks like this in Outlook[image]

But it should look like this:
[image]

I realy hope that someone can help me with this :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet will be to inline or all CSS (which you have done as you have said) and use tables. Outlook doesnt work with DIV's.

If you run this code you can see that its the same as your just in tables. One thing to note is Outlook doesn't read CSS3 elements (border radius, shadows etc). You can still use CSS in the head but it will be read by a few emails clients that support them.

```html
<body style="background-color: #fafafa;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="wrapper" style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 24px 0 24px 0;background-color: #fafafa;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
 
  <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 90%;max-width: 680px;min-width: 280px;border: 1px solid #dddddd;background-color: #ffffff !important;box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.9);margin: auto;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
  
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="inner" style="color: #505050;font-size: 13px;padding: 24px;background-color: #ffffff;">
 
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 30px;line-height: 34px;color: #505050;border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;margin-bottom: 32px;padding-bottom: 8px;background-color: #ffffff"><img src="CENSORED" width="168" height="47" alt="CENSORED" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="color: #505050;font-size: 13px;padding: 24px 0px; background-color: #ffffff;">Schönen guten Tag {name},<br /> Ihre Anfrage ist bei uns eingegangen. Wir bemühen uns um eine schnelle Antwort, um Ihnen weiterhelfen zu können. Sie hören bald wieder von uns!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;margin-top: 32px;padding-top: 8px;font-size: 12px;font-style: italic;color: #707070;background-color:#ffffff;">CENSORED</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 
   
   </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

   
   
   </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 
   
   </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table> 
</body>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Just a quick note, 95% of email clients now support media queries (including Gmail) so you can use media queries to beautify your emails further but make sure to have fallbacks for email clients that dont support fancy stuff. Happy coding bro.

Answer (score 4):

Lots of email clients strip out `<style>` tags from your emails so you should put your styles inline.

You can do this automatically with a [CSS Inliner Tool](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) like the one Mailchimp offers.

Comment: In your HTML code there is no inline CSS. You reference the styles that are located within your CSS. This is most likely the problem.

Comment: Hi All, just wanted to put it out there, more than 95% of devices now support media queries (even Gmail app). Its a little tricky with Gmail app but it works. But yes inline still have to be done for emails clients like Samsung mobiles.

Comment: Gmail will strip out style sheets that contain css it doesn't support. Other clients do strip out style sheets. But that doesn't matter because Outlook doesn't strip out a style sheet. So I create an Outlook-specific one to  incorporate Outlook idiosyncrasies.

Comment: You can overcome the `<style>` being stripped by duplicating it within the body.  Not nice but it saves some email clients.  I do not use this method but I used to and it worked.  Not so many email clients require inline styles now as used to.

Answer (score 0):

As per the outlook specific css you use below style in your html body

```
<!--[if mso]>
  <style type="text/css">
    /*your css here*/ ul { margin: 0px !important; }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```